# Checking to see if data is already in a PSQL database Using PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, psql

I have a sign up web page which connects to postgres database using PHP.

the database is as follows :

```
 id | first_name | last_name |       email        |  uid  | pwd  
----+------------+-----------+--------------------+-------+------
  9 | David      | Jones     | davidjones@one.com | admin | 111
 10 | John       | Stone     | js@bbb.com         | 5     | 222
 11 | a          | Stone     | js@ccc.com         | admin | 333
 12 | David      | f         | js@ccc.com         | admin | 4444
```

I want to check if when the uid (username) is inputted in the webpage it checks the uid to see if has been used already.
I code i am creating is as follows (all the other checks empty fields email valid and input work just the user name check dosn't work)  :

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

   include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

   $first = ($_POST[first]);
   $last = ($_POST[last]);
   $email = ($_POST[email]);
   $uid = ($_POST[uid]);
   $pwd = ($_POST[pwd]);

  // valadate the sign up form
    // check for empty fields
if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
     header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
     exit();
    }else{
    //check if email is valid   
       if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
               header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalidemail");
               exit();
           } else { 
           // check to see if user name is already been used
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid=$uid";
               $result = pg_query($sql);
               $resultCheck = pg_numrows($result);

               if ($resultCheck > 0){
                   header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
                   exit();
               } else {    
   // insert data into users table
   $query="INSERT INTO users (first_name,Last_name,email,uid,pwd) VALUES ('$_POST[first]','$_POST[last]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[uid]','$_POST[pwd]')";
   $result = pg_query($query);
   // go back to the sign up page
   header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
  }     
 }    
}
   ?>
```

Can any one help me?
Many Thanks 
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use single quotes around $uid, because it is string.
So this should work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
```

You could also try using prepared statements instead, then you don't have to use single quotes for string, but instead pass type of data as parameter (usually `string` or `integer`). It will also protect you from SQL Injection, common attack type against websites that your code is vulnerable to.

In PHP popular way to use prepared statements is PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php